# How to show the google plus activity of a Logged in User on the Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having Rails App,in which I want to show the Google Plus activity of logged in User.

I used the Gem Google_plus,but I am having error
GooglePlus::RequestError: GooglePlus::RequestError

Can any one suggest me that How to use this gem or any other gem available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/seejohnrun/google_plus gem "google_plus"  and code 
person = GooglePlus::Person.get(123, :access_token => 'token').
The token that I am passing is stored in my database that is received by omniauth authentication for google.

Comment: Yes.. i am trying to do the same..
but cannot able to achieve...
is it really possible in G+??